# waterfall can't find object 'subtotal' not found

Tags: r, waterfall

When i run waterfall package in R, it says

> "Error in waterfallchart.formula(value ~ label, data = rasiel, groups
>   = subtotal, : object 'subtotal' not found"

does anyone know issue? Thanks.

> `library(latticeExtra)
>   library(waterfall)
>   data(rasiel) # Example data of the waterfall package
>   rasiel
>   asTheEconomist(
>                  waterfallchart(value~label, data=rasiel,
>                                 groups=subtotal, main="P&L")
>                  )`

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, it is not  using the rasiel closure

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(waterfall)
data(rasiel) # Example data of the waterfall package
rasiel
asTheEconomist(
                 waterfallchart(value~label, data=rasiel,
                                groups=rasiel$subtotal, main="P&L")
                 )
```